# Format error while trying to enumerate inside tabulary

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table with the tabulary environment, and I want one of the boxes to contain an enumerated list. I have a great number of these lists in my paper, and the first item in each list is a little buggy. It shows all of the numbers in the list on top of each other, almost creating a little black box. Does anyone know how to get rid of this nuisance?

I get this error message: 
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabulary}{1\textwidth}{ | m{2.1cm} | L | }
         \hline
         \textbf{ID} & ID \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Name} & Name \\
         \hline
         Verifiability & 
         \begin{enumerate}
           \item Step 1
           \item Step 2
           \item Step 3
         \end{enumerate} \\
         \hline
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you're much more likely to get help if you made a full (but small) example that can be copied and tested as is, Here people have to guess your document class and preamble

Comment: And (3) always a good idea to cite the error message

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: After the edits I have made a new document and reproduced this error with the code that is provided in the question, so I hope this will make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can make lists safe during the test run:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\def\zz{%
\ifx\[$%
\let\enumerate\empty
\let\endenumerate\empty
\let\item\relax
\fi}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabulary}{1\textwidth}{ | m{2.1cm} | >{\zz}L | }
         \hline
         \textbf{ID} & ID \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Name} & Name \\
         \hline
         Verifiability & 
         \begin{enumerate}
           \item Step 1
           \item Step 2
           \item Step 3
         \end{enumerate} \\
         \hline
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```